# Unable to trigger event handler on 'DOMContentLoaded' event

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, addeventlistener, domcontentloaded

I'm trying to print output to console when a document is loaded. Below is the code I have written. But there's no output displayed.

```
  var div = document.querySelector('#red');
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function (){
        console.log('event triggered...');
        });
```

Output is displayed correctly when I use below code. Can you please explain me the reason for this behavior?

```
var div = document.querySelector('#red');

window.addEventListener('load',function (){
console.log('event triggered...');
});
```

My simple HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>enlitle</title>
    <link href='styleSheet.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' id='linkElement' /> 

    <script async type='text/javascript' src='scripts.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id='blue'>
            <div id='red'>
            </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use the `defer` tag rather than the `async` tag, because the script depends on the document being fully parsed.

Comment: can you please give the full src to your scripts so that we can try it outside

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me, check this https://jsbin.com/saruhe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: As @CertainPerformance pointed out, it's working only if I remove or replace 'asycn' tag with 'defer'